# whats wrong with my java code to compute the say of the week for a given date

Tags: java

The pseudocode for an algorithm to compute the day of the week for a given
date from the year 1753 onwards is as follows.
Let
d
be the day of the month (from 1 up to 31),
m
be an integer denoting the
month of the year (where
1
denotes January,
2
denotes February, and so on),
and
y
denote the year. The algorithm then performs the following steps in order:

```
If m is less than 3
Add 12 to m and subtract one from y
End if
Set C to be the year of the century (e.g., 10 for the year 2010)
Set D to be the century (e.g., 20 for the year 2010)
Divide 13 * (m + 1) by 5 and call the quotient W
Divide C by 4 and call the quotient X
Divide D by 4 and call the quotient Y
Set Z to be W + X + Y + d + C - 2 * D
Divide Z by 7 and call the remainder day
If day is less than 0
Add 7 to day
End if
```

The value of
day
then gives the day of the week, with
0=
Saturday,
1=
Sunday, up
to
6=
Friday

the code i have so far is:

```
public static String dayOfWeek( SimpleDate date ) {
        // TO BE COMPLETED
        int[] d = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
        int[] m = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        int y = SimpleDate(int year);

        if (m < 3) {
            m + 12;
            y - 1;
        }
        C = SimpleDate(int year[2:3];
        D = SimpleDate(int year[0:1];
        W = 13 * (m + 1) / 5;
        X = C / 4;
        Y = D / 4;
        Z = W + X + Y + d + C - 2 * D;
        day = Z % 7;
        if (day < 0) {
            day + 7;
        }
```

im not sre how to set the year for C and D and at the beginning aswell.
also where i ahve used code such as m + 12 i get an error saying that + is not a statment

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: Please ask a specific question and you might receive a specific answer.  In its current state, this question basically amounts to: "_please do my homework for me_".  A good first step towards getting people to understand your code would be to use sensible variable names.  Your current code is pretty meaningless to any outsider.

Comment: Your question and code indicates that you need to spend some more time learning the basics of Java programming.  For example, your code is full of non-statements like `m + 12` and `y - 1`.  This site doesn't exist so students can throw together a bunch of non-sensical code and expect others to do their homework for them.  Just as a quick hint, you should replace `m + 1` with `m = m + 1`.

Comment: This will get you started: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html. Hope it's not due tomorrow. You probably won't get it done tonight.

Comment: Is `year[2:3]` and `year[0:1]` meant to be python??

Answer (score 2):

How about using `java.util.Calendar` and do

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: Probably not an option for this blatantly obvious homework assignment...

Comment: you can do that,but as you see OP's code, its obvious that its an assignment of some sort

Comment: First you have to set the calendar's date to the given date. You may want to edit that in :)

Comment: @stepanian - I think it's understood that the calendar can be set to any date.

Answer (score 1):

Using [joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html):

```
MutableDateTime dateTimeInstance = new MutableDateTime().setYear(year).setMonth(month).setDay(dayOfMonth); // and so on per [the docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html)
String dayName = dateTimeInstance.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
```

Comment: Same problem as Jigar's answer. This will give you today's day of the week not a given date :) Come on guys, this is too simple :)

Comment: @stepanian - I think it's understood that you could use this approach on any date.  As it pertains to this question, it really doesn't matter.  It's pretty obvious that the OP has a lot of work to do towards understanding the basics of Java.

Comment: @jahroy If you have gone as far as answering such a simple question, then you might as well include the gory details.